# [linux][x86]How to force USB 3.0 combo controller to work in USB 2.0 mode?

Tags: linux, usb

I have a device (x86 architecture) running linux and it can recognize Usb 3.0 storage device correctly. Now I want to force the port to work in Usb 2.0 mode, that is, by entering command lsusb I can result like:

> /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
>   /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
>      |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=, Driver=usb-storage, 480M

I have tried the following methods but none would work:
1.Uninstall xhci driver by command -- not working,it disable Usb 2.0 as well.

> echo -n 'xxxxxx' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
>   (where xxxxx is the pcie number of my usb controller)

2.Plug in the usb 3.0 storage device, then unbind the driver and power off specific Usb 3.0 port by register -- This only work for one of the many usb storage devices for testing.

> echo '2-1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
>   power off Usb port by 'Port Status and Control Register'

3.Power off the Usb port by hardware(cut off the 5V wire for the port)
power off specific Usb 3.0 port by register(but keep the Usb 2.0 port on)
plug in the Usb 3.0 storage device
power on the Usb port by hardware(relink the 5V wire for the port)

Also not working, now it can't recognize any of my Usb storage device.

Any suggestions? I can really use some help here.